# How to generate all combinations of ranges of numbers

Tags: python, c, algorithm, combinations

I have multiple ranges of numbers like [1->5], [1->3] and [1->2]. The amount of ranges and boundaries is variable.

What would be the algorithm (ideally c code) to generate all possible combinations, e.g. for example above:
1 - 1 - 1
1 - 1 - 2
1 - 2 - 1
1 - 2 - 2
1 - 3 - 1
1 - 3 - 2
2 - 1 - 1
...

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a natural problem for a recursive implementation.

Comment: Or for nested loops if the number of ranges is fixed and small.

Comment: Have you any thoughts of your own on this?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I had thought. But the fact the amount of ranges is variable blocks me.

Comment: As @kfx wrote: the recursive solution - perhaps some kind soul will post some code to save you the trouble, but you should really tackle it yourself. Pass the array pointer, the index, the max index, and a value range array as function arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian Product of multiple arrays in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451525/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to be recursive. A sample code in python is:

```
def variads(lst, lstsofar):
    offset = len(lstsofar)
    outerlen = len(lst)
    innerLst = lst[offset]
    printit = False
    if offset == (outerlen - 1):
        printit = True
    for item in innerLst:
        if printit:
            print (lstsofar + [item])
        else:
            variads(lst, lstsofar + [item])
    return
```

To call this you will need to pass a list of lists:

```
>>> variads([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2]], [])
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2]
[1, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 2]
[2, 2, 1]
[2, 2, 2]
[2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 2]
[3, 1, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 1]
[3, 3, 2]
[4, 1, 1]
[4, 1, 2]
[4, 2, 1]
[4, 2, 2]
[4, 3, 1]
[4, 3, 2]
[5, 1, 1]
[5, 1, 2]
[5, 2, 1]
[5, 2, 2]
[5, 3, 1]
[5, 3, 2]
```

The above will handle a variable number of ranges. The ranges are expanded in the call to `variads`. If you just have the max and min, you could write a helper function to expand the ranges and then call `variads`.

Comment: Even though this isn't in C, it shows the algorithm perfectly so I like this answer

Comment: Yes, and OP still has to attempt his own code.

Comment: Oops, didn't see that. I have seen that Python is concise and typically shows the algorithm well (and is hence easier to write and read). Often times in C / C++ a lot of clarity is lost in the code to create / initialize / declare lists. So I like using python to give both working code and display the method used.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense !

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [heaps algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm), as a method.  Also, Knuth has a volume (4b IIRC) dedicated to combinatorics.